# Python: 0 a esquerda string

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, tabela-html

Estou com uma planilha que possui "ID" de clientes. Imagem abaixo.

Com a biblioteca Pandas, estou adicionando cada ID em uma posição de uma lista(`list`).

Mas quando eu adiciono cada elemento, o Python converte em INT eles perdem os 0 da esquerda, ficando `lista = list(1234,1235,1236...)`

O que eu preciso é adicionar em uma lista como string para preservar o 0 da esquerda, ficando `lista = list('0000001234', '0000001235', '0000001236'...)`

Alguém tem alguma ideia ?

[image: tabela]

Comment: Se você preencher a lista utilizando colchete "[]" funciona sem nenhum tipo de problemas. Exemplo: lista = ['0000001234', '0000001235', '0000001236']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você poderia reconverter o id para string e adicionar os zeros faltantes a esquerda alem disso como você esta trabalhando com pandas você pode definir o tipo do campo para texto para preservar o os zeros no seu dataframe

```py
original_lenght = len('0000001234')
id = int('0000001234')
id_converted = '0'*(original_lenght - len(str(id))) + str(id)
print(id)
print(id_converted)

#ouput
#1234
#0000001234

import pandas
frame = pandas.DataFrame([{"id":id_converted}])
frame['id'] = frame['id'].astype(str)
frame.head()

#output

#   id
# 0000001234
```

Comment: usa pyformat pra fazer as strings com 0 a esquerda: `id_converted='{:0{lenght}}'.format(id, lenght=original_lenght)`